# Sibilance/aspiration in the letter D in "don't", "day" etc

Tags: pronunciation, aspiration

I can't seem to find anything explaining this, but on words like "don't" and "day", some people pronounce the D with a sibilant sound/aspiration and others like a dead D with no aspiration.

I have some examples here with the word "don't":

The first two pronunciations in the American English here, where the first is sibilant and the second is dead: https://forvo.com/word/don%27t/

sibilant D: https://youtu.be/YZG7z4FOn0g?si=y4Jk2ErqgyITrpS_?t=86 at 1:26

sibilant D: https://youtu.be/NCtzkaL2t_Y?si=czD97JPA-wiZJSJM at 0:04

dead D: https://youtu.be/aef2eV7GmQw?t=238 from 3:58 to the end

dead D: https://youtu.be/nfsWdOvtkSU?si=G2hUh14Makji52CF at 0:51

There seems to be a big difference for something that isn't mentioned anywhere. This can be found in lots of words starting with D, like "day", "down" and so on.

Comment: Minor differences in accents aren't likely to be included in dictionaries. You'd need at least dozen pronunciations to cover multiple countries and regional accents within each.

Comment: There is nothing about grammar here, only the different shape of people's teeth and tongues.

Comment: @WeatherVane Where is grammar mentioned?

Comment: In the last example, the lyric at 0:51 is "good at", not "don't".

Comment: @Barmar it's actually between 0:52 and 0:53, where she says "I don't want someone missing me"

Comment: I think that what you may be recognizing is the fact that word-initial /d/ is sometimes devoiced, essentially becoming an unaspirated [t]. In the two examples you provide from Forvo, the one that you call a "dead" /d/ appears to have a more fully voiced sound, whereas the "sibilant" one has an audible period of voicelessness at the start.

Comment: @alphabet I'm really sorry for asking, but would you mind going into more details about this? I googled it and can't understand what exactly Is a devoiced /d/ and voicelessness. What is the change compared to the voiced /d/?

Comment: I can't hear any difference. But if I use my imagination, The Beatles need to take a big breath in front of the first measure of the first word of the song. Some air is going to come out with that *Don’t*.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueQuiste Sadly I only *kind of* understand the phonetics behind all this; I'll leave it to someone more qualified to answer.

Comment: Comparing spoken sounds with sung sounds is comparing apples and oranges. And how can an initial d be sibilant??

Comment: Oasis are from Manchester and the Beatles were from Liverpool, both in the northwest. I'm no expert on British dialects but I would expect some Irish influence; in heavy Dublin accent I'd almost hear "dshon't".

Comment: Please note: **Aspiration is not about consonants, it's about vowels**.  For example, when English speakers over-aspirate vowels in Spanish, you can tell they are English speakers. Too much **air** comes out with the vowel sound instead of being stopped. So, el banco sounds like el bancoh; la chica sounds like la chicah. It is the o sound in banco an the a sounds in la chica that are aspirated. Aspiration is about the **release of air** and English speakers do not over-aspirate their own vowel sounds in day and don't.

Answer (score 1):

From the clips you shared, by "dead" /d/ I suppose you mean unaspirated /d/ (or maybe tapped /d/, see the last paragraph of this answer). With that, there's a section in "*Cambridge English Pronouncing Dictionary*, Cambridge University Press" describing a similar phenomenon you mentioned, i.e., some speakers tend to add /s/ after /t/ so it becomes /ts/, thus sounding "sibilant" as you put it. For example <time> would be pronounced as /tsaim/.

So it's quite natural to expect the same phenomenon to occur for /d/ since lenis consonants in English are often devoiced (especially when they're at the start/end of the speech) and particularly in singing where special "effects" are often added to sounds.

Also in American English, /t/ and also /d/ can be tapped (or some would say flapped), that is, tongue tip makes a quick contact with the alveolar, so the *hold* phase (the time when the airflow is compressed between articulators before being released) may be significantly weakened or even absent.

Answer (score 0):

These minor differences tend to be associated with different accents, and dictionaries simply don't bother trying to cover all the regions, it would require several pronunciation guides for almost every word. So they only list major differences in pronunciation, such as highly noticeable vowel variations, whether or not a letter is silent, etc. You'll rarely see more than two or three pronunciations for a word.

They're not going to bother with two pronunciations for every word beginning with "d", to show both aspirated and non-aspirated variations. It's not a difference that most people would even notice.

More generally, dictionaries can generally only go into a limited amount of detail before they become unweildy. Lexicographers are always making judgement calls about what nuances to list as separate senses or definitions, and similar judgement is used for pronunciation (but they tend to be even more conservative).

Comment: That makes sense! So there's no rule or even a more common used version here?

Comment: Nope, just judgement calls by the dictionary compilers.

Comment: I can't even hear any sibilance. I suppose what sounds you can distinguish depends on your native language.

Comment: @KateBunting really? I think the difference is pretty clear between the second example in the sibilant/aspirated D and the second example in the dead D sound

Comment: It's essentially impossible to aspirate a voiced /d/ in the same way that word-initial voiced /t/s get aspirated.